# Find which RDS is using a certain parameter group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How can I find which RDS database (if any) is using a certain [parameter group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html)?

Clicking through each DB to check that is not a solution. There's too many DBs in the organization.

Comment: There might be a way using the API. Or if you delete it maybe it'll tell you? In future tagging can help, if people use it, if that's a resource that can be tagged.

Answer (score 2):

You can query each instance to check what Parameter Groups it's using. The PG itself won't tell you.

try doing a
`aws rds describe-db-instances --query DBInstances[].[DBInstanceIdentifier,DBParameterGroups]`
to get a full listing. If you have too many instances you'll likely need to page the calls.